# A program that would show no error but would not give the desired outcome

Tags: c

In a town, the percentage of men is 52.The percentage of total literacy is 48. If total percentage of literate men is 35 of total population, find the total number of illiterate men and women separately.The population of the town is 80,000.

There is that question in my math book and I tried to write a program on it.

After building the program, the compiler showed no error but the program would not give the desired outcome. I rewrote the program many times and the code given below is my final one. I am thinking that there must be some arithmetical association error but could not figure out where.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int men, wmen, litm, litwo, illit, lit, tot=80000, illitwmen;
    men = (52/100) * 80000;
    wmen = tot-men;
    lit = (48/100) * 80000;
    litm = (35/100) * 80000;
    litwo = lit-litm;
    illitwmen = wmen-litwo;
    printf("Hence the total illiterate men of the town is %d\n", men-litm);
    printf("Hence the total illiterate women is %d\n", illitwmen);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Watch for integer division, (52/100) == 0

Comment: I used float instead of int and still did not get the desired outcome.

Comment: Still integer division, if you did not type (52.0/100.0)

Comment: @AaKASH - Please mark that answer as correct if that is indeed what helped you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem, just use `double`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double men,wmen,litm,litwo,illit,lit,tot=80000,illitwmen;
    men=(52.0/100.0)*80000.0;
    wmen=tot-men;
    lit=(48.0/100.0)*80000.0;
    litm=(35.0/100.0)*80000.0;
    litwo=lit-litm;
    illitwmen=wmen-litwo;
    printf("Hence the total illiterate men of the town is %d\n",men-litm);
    printf("Hence the total illiterate women is %d\n",illitwmen);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I hate mobile answering

Answer (score 1):

Use instead (if you want to stay with integers):

```
men=(52*80000)/100;
wmen=tot-men;
lit=(48*80000)/100;
litm=(35*80000)/100;
```

Also, you may have to deal with rounding.